# How to limit output filesize of ffmpeg input stream to 10 megabytes

Tags: ffmpeg

I am subscribing to an input stream from tvheadend using ffmpeg and I am writing that stream to disk continuously . I'd like to limit this output stream so that there are 10 megabytes of data stored at maximum at any time.

I already looked into sponge from moreutils and the linux buffer command to build some kind of a pipe . Though, I could not find a working solution yet. Who can point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need just `-fs` key.
It sets output filesize limit in bytes.

You can type `ffmpeg -i input -fs 10M -c copy output`, where `input` is your input address, `output` - filename you want your file to have. `M` specifies that you want size in megabytes (also `k` for kilobytes is allowed).

---

For overwriting you can use a small sript like this

```
#!/bin/bash

t=1
while :
do
 ffmpeg -i input -fs 10M -c copy output$t
 t=`expr $t + 1`
done
```

I think this is more elegant than trying to do everything using ffmpeg only.

Comment: thanx. the -fs option will stop ffmpeg. I'd like to overwrite the segment continuosly. I think I found a good solution that is quite close to what I need. -f ssegment -segment_time 60 -segment_wrap 2 tmp/out%03d.ts

Comment: Please, see the edit I made: there's a small script that can help you.

Comment: Thanks. I disagree though. It is more elegant to use a native ffmpeg function  instead of implementing sth. external. But since your solution is more exact I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: Can I also use `G` as the unit for Gigabyte?

Comment: @QinHeyang I can't tell right away from looking at a documentation. I guess you can simply try. I thinm it'll fail if `G` is not a right option

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  FFmpeg just ignores the file limit I set with `-fs`.  My command is something like `ffmpeg -i <input> -fs 128k -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -an <output.mp4>`.  I am trying to generate short low-quality "thumbnail" videos.